# margin:0 auto; width:1024; causes horizontal visible document reflow onload, why?

Tags: html, css, reflow

I can reproduce this problem in multiple websites with different designs.
Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this on jsfiddle since it doesn't have full screen.

In both cases there is a body or div element with something like:

```
<body style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 1024px; min-width:1024px; max-width:1024px;>
```

And the page gets visible reflow after 200ms (somewhere around onload event). What causes horizontal reflow when using auto margin?

Example:

This page has reflow:
http://www.numbeo.com/common/form.jsp?country=United+States&city=San+Diego%2C+CA&returnUrl=%2Fcost-of-living%2Fcity_result.jsp%3Fcountry%3DUnited%2BStates%26city%3DSan%2BDiego%252C%2BCA

The following doesn't have it:
http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/calculator.jsp

Comment: It seems it's because off the scrollbar. First the page gets a (vertical) scrollbar, even when it is not necessary, and then it disappears.

Comment: it indeed looks like it's due to vertical scrollbar, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the Facebook/tweeter bar and see if this still happens... And from there you can work on that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

Kudos to SKeurentjes!